# Ruby Rails - Create Entry, Hash Has Extraneous Keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A rails table `Book` which just has one column named `title`.

```
Book.create( { title: "A Gay Science", rating: 10 })
`rescue in _assign_attribute': unknown attribute 'rating'
```

This is a simplified example... Right now I loop through a list of such hashes which have extraneous keys and either delete the offenders or generate a new list of fresh hashes to insert into the database.  Is there a better way, maybe a method already designed to deal with this issue?

Comment: You can add `attr_accessor :rating` to `Book` which should make it accept the values, but won't save it to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the list of array like below,

```
array = [{ title: "A Gay Science", rating: 10 }, { title: "A Gay Science", rating: 10 }, { title: "A Gay Science", rating: 10 }]
```

You can do something like this,

```
array.each do |a| 
Book.create(title: a[:title])
end
```